# Configuration Processing server Sitecore 8.2 update 5

Tags: processing

I am trying to configure the `Processing server` according this architecture. 2 server for CD, `Reporting server` and CM in the one single server and Processing in another server. I am configuring according this link the `Processing server`:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-a-processing-server.html

It is not clear how is the configuration in **step-4** (`Connection string`) and **step-5** (`Configuration files`) with the architecture indicated above because `Reporting server` has a separated column?

Additionally I don't know if it is required additional configuration to complete the configuration of the `Processing server`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the following Roles per server, you will need to enable and disable specific configs on each server based on the role/roles you want for that server.

Download the excel sheet [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/resources/Config-Enable-Disable-Sitecore-8.2-Update2-5.xlsx) and for each server do the following:

- Server 1 (CMS, Reporting) :

  - Enable any config file in the sheet if it says **Enable** in **either** CM or Reporting columns.
  - Disable any config file in the sheet if it says **Disable** in **both** CM or Reporting columns.
- Server 2 (Processing):

  - Enable any config file in the sheet if it says **Enable** in Processing column.
  - Disable any config file in the sheet if it says **Disable** in Processing column.
- Server 3&4 (CD):

  - Enable any config file in the sheet if it says **Enable** in CD column.
  - Disable any config file in the sheet if it says **Disable** in CD column.

CM server does need to know where is the processing server, since by enabling/disabling proper configs will define each server roles.

One thing i would recommend is that you have scheduled task that ping your processing server so that the sitecore instance does not go idle.

Answer (score 0):

As per explanation from your question, since your reporting server is combined with CM, you don't need to consider the reporting service column in the documentation link.

Here are the connection string you should configure for your Processing Server

1. Core
2. Master
3. Reporting
4. Reporting Secondary (if you have secondary reporting DB)

**Analytics**

1. analytics
2. tracking.live
3. tracking.history
4. tracking.contact

Refer https://doc.sitecore.com/resources/Config-Enable-Disable-Sitecore-8.2-Update2-5.xlsx **reporting** column which files you need to enable in your CM server. You can safely ignore config files with "RemoteServer"

Comment: Ok thanks, checking the configuration it is not clear in what part is set the configuration to link the specific processing server. It seems that CM and processing server are separated servers without reference between both of them. I don´t know if I need to configure also the following configuration https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-security-keys-on-servers-in-a-scaled-environment.html